# editor.commit ( API 1) vs. editor.apply (API 9). What to do?

Tags: android, android-studio, commit

I got a warning on this statement:

`editor.commit();`

AS 1.1.0 suggests using `.apply()` instead since it works in background, whereas `.commit()` writes immediately.

But `apply` requires API 9 and up; `commit` has been around forever.

I'm inclined to NOT make the change since I only have a handful of preferences.

Besides, what happens if `apply` gets executed on an older device?

Comment: Well, according to Android [dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone) API level 9 covers 99.7% of devices.

Comment: What happens if `apply` gets executed under API 8 or less?

Answer (score 1):

> But apply requires API 9 and up

At the present time, [~99.7% of Android devices accessing the Play Store are running API Level 10 or higher](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

> I'm inclined to NOT make the change since I only have a handful of preferences.

Then wrap a call to `commit()` in your own thread, to do the disk I/O on a background thread.

> what happens if apply gets executed on an older device?

If your `compileSdkVersion` is 9 or higher, and your `minSdkVersion` is below 9, and you use `apply()`, the build tools should point out to you that this is a mistake. If you persist, you will crash, probably with a `VerifyError`.